# Can a standard Rx/Tx bluetooth module send and receive at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth

I can a simple bluetooth module receive and transmit data at the same time? Or will it require a secondary antennta or even another bluetooth chip?

Comment: Not sure you can, but is it really necessary?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of self-diagnosis mode?

Comment: I am thinking of a real time fast bluetooth relay.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is “full-duplex”.

“Bluetooth technology provides the effect of full duplex transmission through the use of a time-division duplex (TDD) scheme.”

https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/OverviewOfOperations.aspx

[Edit: since it gives you the effect of full-duplex you don't need a second antenna/module.]